# how to use img in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I create images folder in src folder and I put All my images into and I am trying to use img with different method but no one it working ?

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /budjet.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

```
import Lo from '/images/budjet.jpg';

<ReactRoundedImage
  image={Lo}
  roundedColor="#321124"
  imageWidth="300"
  imageHeight="300"
  roundedSize="13"
  hoverColor="#DD1144"/>



<img src={ require('/images/budjet.jpg').default} class="img-circle mtimg" alt="pp" />

 <img src={ require('./images/budjet.jpg').default} class="img-circle mtimg" alt="pp" />
```

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: yes I am using create-react-app

Comment: check with this script  <img  src={Lo} ... />

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your image to your images folder  and put it to  public folder in your  project  and use this it work for me

```
<img src="images/budget.jpg" class="img-circle mtimg" alt="pp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `create-react-app`, there are two ways to add images to your pages (regarding the `src` attribute).

1. Put them in `public` folder.

> You can access them like so:
>
> ```
> <img src ="/my-img.png" alt="" />
> ```
>
> `/` means the `public` folder. If you have your images say inside a folder called `imgs`put inside `public` folder, you access them like this:
>
> ```
> <img src ="/imgs/my-img.png" alt="" />
> ```

2. You can put your images inside `src` folder, and use them like this:

> ```
> import img from 'relative-path/my-img.png'
> ```
>
> ```
> <img src ={img} alt="" />
> ```